# In Polymer, why use `<input is="iron-input">` instead of `<iron-input>`?

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

In the Polymer document (https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-input), I found:

```
<input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">
```

And in another official document (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#type-extension) , I found:

```
    <dom-module id="main-document-element">
      <template>
        <p>
          Hi! I'm a Polymer element that was defined in the
          main document!
        </p>
      </template>
      <script>
        HTMLImports.whenReady(function () {
          Polymer({
            is: 'main-document-element'
          });
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
    <main-document-element></main-document-element>
```

I was just wondering why the first one `<input is="iron-input" bind-value="{{myValue}}">` can't be written as `<iron-input bind-value="{{myValue}}">`.

Is it for compatibility, which makes it easier to polyfill?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `iron-input` element does not contain any HTML in its source code. This means that doing:

```
<iron-input bind-value="{{myValue}}">
```

will not produce an actual input on the page for the user to interact with. The `iron-input` element is really a collection of behaviours that you can apply to a standard HTML input.